# Group the Coordinates under each Mappoint

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to use XSLT to process data by grouping it.

Sample XML

```
  <DELIVERYLEG>
        <DELIVERYINSTRUCTION>
            <MAP_REFERENCE_SYSTEM>EUREF-FIN</MAP_REFERENCE_SYSTEM>
            <MAP_COORDINATE_TYPE>ETRS-TM35FIN</MAP_COORDINATE_TYPE>
            <XY_TEXT>XY</XY_TEXT>
            <maprows>
                <MAP_POINT_TOTAL_ROWS>18</MAP_POINT_TOTAL_ROWS>
                <MAP_POINT_ROW>3</MAP_POINT_ROW>
                <MAP_POINT_NAME>695123</MAP_POINT_NAME>
                <MAP_POINT_GROUP>3</MAP_POINT_GROUP>
                <MAP_POINT_DISPLAY_TYPE>UserWay</MAP_POINT_DISPLAY_TYPE>
                <COORDINATE_DISPLAY_ORDER>1</COORDINATE_DISPLAY_ORDER>
                <MAP_POINT_TYPE>Turning</MAP_POINT_TYPE>
                <MAP_POINT_COORDINATES>695123</MAP_POINT_COORDINATES>
                <MAP_POINT_COMMENT>SALMI AINO</MAP_POINT_COMMENT>
            </maprows>
            <maprows>
                <MAP_POINT_TOTAL_ROWS>18</MAP_POINT_TOTAL_ROWS>
                <MAP_POINT_ROW>4</MAP_POINT_ROW>
                <MAP_POINT_NAME>6951337</MAP_POINT_NAME>
                <MAP_POINT_GROUP>5</MAP_POINT_GROUP>
                <MAP_POINT_DISPLAY_TYPE>Line</MAP_POINT_DISPLAY_TYPE>
                <COORDINATE_DISPLAY_ORDER>1</COORDINATE_DISPLAY_ORDER>
                <MAP_POINT_TYPE>ForestRoad</MAP_POINT_TYPE>
                <MAP_POINT_COORDINATES>6951337</MAP_POINT_COORDINATES>
                <MAP_POINT_COMMENT />
            </maprows>
            <maprows>
                <MAP_POINT_TOTAL_ROWS>18</MAP_POINT_TOTAL_ROWS>
                <MAP_POINT_ROW>5</MAP_POINT_ROW>
                <MAP_POINT_NAME>6951271</MAP_POINT_NAME>
                <MAP_POINT_GROUP>5</MAP_POINT_GROUP>
                <MAP_POINT_DISPLAY_TYPE>Line</MAP_POINT_DISPLAY_TYPE>
                <COORDINATE_DISPLAY_ORDER>2</COORDINATE_DISPLAY_ORDER>
                <MAP_POINT_TYPE>ForestRoad</MAP_POINT_TYPE>
                <MAP_POINT_COORDINATES>6951271</MAP_POINT_COORDINATES>
                <MAP_POINT_COMMENT />
            </maprows>
            <maprows>
                <MAP_POINT_TOTAL_ROWS>18</MAP_POINT_TOTAL_ROWS>
                <MAP_POINT_ROW>6</MAP_POINT_ROW>
                <MAP_POINT_NAME>6951479</MAP_POINT_NAME>
                <MAP_POINT_GROUP>6</MAP_POINT_GROUP>
                <MAP_POINT_DISPLAY_TYPE>Line</MAP_POINT_DISPLAY_TYPE>
                <COORDINATE_DISPLAY_ORDER>1</COORDINATE_DISPLAY_ORDER>
                <MAP_POINT_TYPE>ForestRoad</MAP_POINT_TYPE>
                <MAP_POINT_COORDINATES>6951479</MAP_POINT_COORDINATES>
                <MAP_POINT_COMMENT />
            </maprows>
            <maprows>
                <MAP_POINT_TOTAL_ROWS>18</MAP_POINT_TOTAL_ROWS>
                <MAP_POINT_ROW>7</MAP_POINT_ROW>
                <MAP_POINT_NAME>6951507</MAP_POINT_NAME>
                <MAP_POINT_GROUP>6</MAP_POINT_GROUP>
                <MAP_POINT_DISPLAY_TYPE>Line</MAP_POINT_DISPLAY_TYPE>
                <COORDINATE_DISPLAY_ORDER>2</COORDINATE_DISPLAY_ORDER>
                <MAP_POINT_TYPE>ForestRoad</MAP_POINT_TYPE>
                <MAP_POINT_COORDINATES>6951507</MAP_POINT_COORDINATES>
                <MAP_POINT_COMMENT />
            </maprows>
            <maprows>
                <MAP_POINT_TOTAL_ROWS>18</MAP_POINT_TOTAL_ROWS>
                <MAP_POINT_ROW>8</MAP_POINT_ROW>
                <MAP_POINT_NAME>6951598</MAP_POINT_NAME>
                <MAP_POINT_GROUP>6</MAP_POINT_GROUP>
                <MAP_POINT_DISPLAY_TYPE>Line</MAP_POINT_DISPLAY_TYPE>
                <COORDINATE_DISPLAY_ORDER>3</COORDINATE_DISPLAY_ORDER>
                <MAP_POINT_TYPE>ForestRoad</MAP_POINT_TYPE>
                <MAP_POINT_COORDINATES>6951598</MAP_POINT_COORDINATES>
                <MAP_POINT_COMMENT />
            </maprows>
            <maprows>
                <MAP_POINT_TOTAL_ROWS>18</MAP_POINT_TOTAL_ROWS>
                <MAP_POINT_ROW>9</MAP_POINT_ROW>
                <MAP_POINT_NAME>6951734</MAP_POINT_NAME>
                <MAP_POINT_GROUP>6</MAP_POINT_GROUP>
                <MAP_POINT_DISPLAY_TYPE>Line</MAP_POINT_DISPLAY_TYPE>
                <COORDINATE_DISPLAY_ORDER>4</COORDINATE_DISPLAY_ORDER>
                <MAP_POINT_TYPE>ForestRoad</MAP_POINT_TYPE>
                <MAP_POINT_COORDINATES>6951734</MAP_POINT_COORDINATES>
                <MAP_POINT_COMMENT />
            </maprows>
        </DELIVERYINSTRUCTION>
    </DELIVERYLEG>
```

It should group on MAP_POINT_GROUP and all coordinate should come under that group.
Below is the output excepted....

```
<MapPoint MapPointDisplayType="Turning" MapPointType="UserWay">
    <MapPointName>695123</MapPointName>
    <MapPointComment>Kom</MapPointComment>
    <MapCoordinates>
        <Coordinates Order="1" Type="XY">695123</Coordinates>
    </MapCoordinates>                          
</MapPoint> 
<MapPoint MapPointDisplayType="Line" MapPointType="ForestRoad">
    <MapPointName>6951271</MapPointName>
    <MapCoordinates>
        <Coordinates Order="1" Type="XY">6951337</Coordinates>
        <Coordinates Order="2" Type="XY">6951271</Coordinates>
    </MapCoordinates>                          
</MapPoint> 
<MapPoint MapPointDisplayType="Line" MapPointType="ForestRoad">
    <MapPointName>6951479</MapPointName>
    <MapCoordinates>
        <Coordinates Order="1" Type="XY">6951479</Coordinates>
        <Coordinates Order="2" Type="XY">6951507</Coordinates>
        <Coordinates Order="3" Type="XY">6951598</Coordinates>
        <Coordinates Order="4" Type="XY">6951734</Coordinates>
    </MapCoordinates>                          
</MapPoint>
```

How would I deal with this?

Below is existing XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0" xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                xmlns:var="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/var"
                exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
                xmlns:userCSharp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/userCSharp"
                xmlns:ReformatDate="http://functions/xslt">

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/DeliveryLeg" />
        <!--<xsl:apply-templates select="/DeliveryLeg" />-->

    </xsl:template>



    <xsl:template match="/DeliveryLeg">
        <DeliveryInstruction>
            <SupplyPoint>
                <xsl:attribute name="LocationType">
                    <xsl:value-of select ="logforce..LF_HEADER_LAHTOVARASTO/logforce..LF_LAHTOVARASTO/ORIGIN_VALUE/text()"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <SupplyPointCode>
                    <xsl:attribute name="Agency">
                        <xsl:value-of select ="logforce..LF_HEADER_LAHTOVARASTO/logforce..LF_LAHTOVARASTO/SUPPLY_POINT_CODE/text()"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select ="logforce..LF_HEADER_LAHTOVARASTO/logforce..LF_LAHTOVARASTO/ERA_NRO/text()"/>
                </SupplyPointCode>
                <SupplyPointCode>
                    <xsl:attribute name="Agency">
                        <xsl:value-of select ="logforce..LF_HEADER_LAHTOVARASTO/logforce..LF_LAHTOVARASTO/LOGISTICS_BUYER/text()"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select ="logforce..LF_HEADER_LAHTOVARASTO/logforce..LF_LAHTOVARASTO/ERA_NRO/text()"/>
                </SupplyPointCode>
                <SupplyPointDescription>
                    <xsl:value-of select ="logforce..LF_HEADER_LAHTOVARASTO/logforce..LF_LAHTOVARASTO/ROADSIDE_STOCK/text()"/>
                </SupplyPointDescription>
                <MapCoordinates>
                    <xsl:attribute name="MapReferenceSystem">
                        <xsl:value-of select ="logforce..LF_HEADER_LAHTOVARASTO/logforce..LF_LAHTOVARASTO/MAP_REFERENCE_SYSTEM/text()"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="MapCoordinateType">
                        <xsl:value-of select ="logforce..LF_HEADER_LAHTOVARASTO/logforce..LF_LAHTOVARASTO/MAP_COORDINATE_TYPE/text()"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <Coordinates>
                        <xsl:attribute name="CoordinateFormatType">
                            <xsl:value-of select ="logforce..LF_HEADER_LAHTOVARASTO/logforce..LF_LAHTOVARASTO/XY_TEXT/text()"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:value-of select ="logforce..LF_HEADER_LAHTOVARASTO/logforce..LF_LAHTOVARASTO/ERA_KOORDINAATIT/text()"/>
                    </Coordinates>
                </MapCoordinates>
                <!--New Logic for MapPoint-->
                <SupplyPointCharacteristics>

                    <NEW CODE SHOULD BE THERE>


                </SupplyPointCharacteristics>
            </SupplyPoint>
        </DeliveryInstruction>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you describe in a little more detail exactly what you mean by the last paragraph?

Comment: I think that was confusion ... so leave it. I have removed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the solution base on  [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="kmaprows" match="maprows" use="MAP_POINT_GROUP"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <row>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//maprows[generate-id() = generate-id( key('kmaprows',MAP_POINT_GROUP)[1]) ]"  />
        </row>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="maprows">
        <MapPoint MapPointDisplayType="{MAP_POINT_TYPE}" MapPointType="{MAP_POINT_TYPE}">
            <MapPointName>
                <xsl:value-of select="MAP_POINT_NAME"/>
            </MapPointName>
            <MapCoordinates>
                <xsl:for-each select="key('kmaprows',current()/MAP_POINT_GROUP)">
                    <Coordinates Order="{position()}" Type="{../XY_TEXT}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="MAP_POINT_NAME"/>
                    </Coordinates>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </MapCoordinates>
        </MapPoint>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which will generate the expected output:

```
<row>
  <MapPoint MapPointDisplayType="Turning" MapPointType="Turning">
    <MapPointName>695123</MapPointName>
    <MapCoordinates>
      <Coordinates Order="1" Type="XY">695123</Coordinates>
    </MapCoordinates>
  </MapPoint>
  <MapPoint MapPointDisplayType="ForestRoad" MapPointType="ForestRoad">
    <MapPointName>6951337</MapPointName>
    <MapCoordinates>
      <Coordinates Order="1" Type="XY">6951337</Coordinates>
      <Coordinates Order="2" Type="XY">6951271</Coordinates>
    </MapCoordinates>
  </MapPoint>
  <MapPoint MapPointDisplayType="ForestRoad" MapPointType="ForestRoad">
    <MapPointName>6951479</MapPointName>
    <MapCoordinates>
      <Coordinates Order="1" Type="XY">6951479</Coordinates>
      <Coordinates Order="2" Type="XY">6951507</Coordinates>
      <Coordinates Order="3" Type="XY">6951598</Coordinates>
      <Coordinates Order="4" Type="XY">6951734</Coordinates>
    </MapCoordinates>
  </MapPoint>
</row>
```

Comment: How to call this in existing XSLT code ?? Should i copy all this code above the existing code or i can paste it whenever this is required  ???

Comment: @user2385547 The `xsl:key` has to be at the top of the stylesheet. The `xsl:template` location do no matter. Problem with existing code would probably be the root template (match="/"). You may have to change this. Hard do say how without knowing more about your existing stylesheet.

Comment: Add the template  `match="maprows"` and the `xsl:key` to the top level in your style sheet. And replace `<NEW CODE SHOULD BE THERE>` with the above applay-templates (`<xsl:apply-templates select="//maprows[generate-id() = generate-id( key('kmaprows',MAP_POINT_GROUP)[1]) ]"  />`)

Comment: One more doubt .... <Coordinates Order="4" Type="XY">6951734</Coordinates> Type="XY" value is one level above main <maprows> so how should i access that one  ????

Comment: Need help ....                                                      One more doubt .... <Coordinates Order="4" Type="XY">6951734</Coordinates> Type="XY" value is one level above main <maprows> so how should i access that one ????

Comment: I do not understand, there is not Coordinates  in your input example. Therefor i do not have any glue what you like to do with them and depending on which condition.

Comment: i have edited Input XML ..  now it is complete xml file coming form customer. In previous result <Coordinates Order="4" Type="XY">6951734</Coordinates>     Type= "XY"   so this should have value from node //DeliveryLeg/DeliveryInstruction/XYTEXT (as per Input file)    i.e. one level above main <maprows>  so how should i access that one ????

Comment: Use `Type="{../XY_TEXT}"`. Please also consider to mark the answer as valid.

Comment: Not working actually i tried giving {DELIVERYLEG/DELIVERYINSTRUCTION/XY_TEXT} also {../XY_TEXT} but not succeeded

Comment: With your changed input xml and the above style sheet it should work and do for me.(XY_TEXT and  maprows have to have the same parent).

Answer (score 0):

I have create some script:

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="group" match="maprows" use="MAP_POINT_GROUP"/>

  <xsl:template match="rows">
    <row>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="maprows[generate-id()=generate-id(key('group',MAP_POINT_GROUP))]"
      />
    </row>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="maprows">
    <xsl:variable name="Group" select="MAP_POINT_GROUP"/>
    <MapPoint MapPointDisplayType="{MAP_POINT_TYPE}" MapPointType="{MAP_POINT_TYPE}">
      <MapPointName>
        <xsl:value-of select="MAP_POINT_NAME"/>
      </MapPointName>
      <MapCoordinates>
        <xsl:for-each select="parent::rows/maprows[MAP_POINT_GROUP=$Group]">
          <Coordinates Order="{position()}" Type="XY">
            <xsl:value-of select="MAP_POINT_NAME"/>
          </Coordinates>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </MapCoordinates>
    </MapPoint>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
<row>
   <MapPoint MapPointDisplayType="Turning" MapPointType="Turning">
      <MapPointName>695123</MapPointName>
      <MapCoordinates>
         <Coordinates Order="1" Type="XY">695123</Coordinates>
      </MapCoordinates>
   </MapPoint>
   <MapPoint MapPointDisplayType="ForestRoad" MapPointType="ForestRoad">
      <MapPointName>6951337</MapPointName>
      <MapCoordinates>
         <Coordinates Order="1" Type="XY">6951337</Coordinates>
         <Coordinates Order="2" Type="XY">6951271</Coordinates>
      </MapCoordinates>
   </MapPoint>
   <MapPoint MapPointDisplayType="ForestRoad" MapPointType="ForestRoad">
      <MapPointName>6951479</MapPointName>
      <MapCoordinates>
         <Coordinates Order="1" Type="XY">6951479</Coordinates>
         <Coordinates Order="2" Type="XY">6951507</Coordinates>
         <Coordinates Order="3" Type="XY">6951598</Coordinates>
         <Coordinates Order="4" Type="XY">6951734</Coordinates>
      </MapCoordinates>
   </MapPoint>
</row>
```

Comment: This is a little bit strange. Crating a key  using it for grouping but not for accessing the elements of the group.